# django gui for statistical analysis of data

Tags: python, django, search, django-statistics

Im trying to setup situation where users of application can do statistical analysis of data.

There are 3 tables, users, exams, polls

I should have gui to build custom queries, like these:

1. users born between 1930 and 1940, that have 3 exams taken; show 
   name, surname, group by age of person
2. count of users born 1945 that have not taken poll grouped by reason;show count,reason

Language of choice is python, django.
If anyone has experience or can recommend some python package that would make my job easier I'd be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some pretty good success recently using Alex Gaynor's `django-filter` app, [located here](http://github.com/alex/django-filter).

It brings a lot of the Django admin's drill-down filtering controls to your site's front-end objects, and after a bit of configuration you should be able to use it to provide a nice set of filters for your User, Exam, and Poll models that anyone can use.

Comment: can I do group by somehow with django filter?

Answer (score 2):

I have developed [django-cube](http://code.google.com/p/django-cube/) for this very purpose.

It allows you to organize your django data as multi-dimensional data, declare an aggregation function (to calculate your statistics), and then you have several helpers to display a table, and ready-to-use Django templates for tables.

Comment: Is there any special reason for choosing GPL instead of Django's BSD licensing?

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is dead, both because I have no time and interest in developing it further.